# SQL: select userIDs with same value on a column in different rows (different months)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table (finances_history) 

It´s only one table, but to show you the content i broke it into 2 blocks, as you can see below :

```
userID || month  || bill   || value 
------------------------------------
u01    || 201401 || energy || 0
u01    || 201402 || energy || 0
------------------------------------
u02    || 201401 || energy || 0
u02    || 201402 || energy || 0
------------------------------------
u03    || 201401 || energy || 75
u03    || 201402 || energy || 0
------------------------------------
u04    || 201401 || energy || 90
u04    || 201402 || energy || 90
------------------------------------
u05    || 201401 || energy || 85
u05    || 201402 || energy || 90
------------------------------------
u06    || 201401 || energy || 0
u06    || 201402 || energy || 0
------------------------------------
```

```
userID || month  || bill   || value 
------------------------------------
u01    || 201401 || rent   || 300
u01    || 201402 || rent   || 300
------------------------------------
u02    || 201401 || rent   || 350
u02    || 201402 || rent   || 400
------------------------------------
u03    || 201401 || rent   || 0
u03    || 201402 || rent   || 0
------------------------------------
u04    || 201401 || rent   || 0
u04    || 201402 || rent   || 0
------------------------------------
u05    || 201401 || rent   || 0
u05    || 201402 || rent   || 0
------------------------------------
u06    || 201401 || rent   || 0
u06    || 201402 || rent   || 0
------------------------------------
```

There are different users on this table, but it records info from different months of a year (in this case only two months, january - 201401, and february - 201402).

Also a same user can have two different kind of bills to pay (in this case only two different kinds, energy and rent), but if a user has one of the bills to pay (in at least one of the months, or both), he will NOT have the other bill (the values will be 0 on the other bill, on both months) ... or i can have an user with both bills with value 0 on both months.

I need to "SELECT" only the users (userID) that have at least one of the bills with value different then 0 (considering the 4 rows, both months) AND where the values of the bill (that is not 0) are the same in both months.

So, what i´m looking for is a "SELECT" that can give me, on my sample above, the users u01 and u04 (the only ones that follow the criteria, at least one bill with value different then 0 in at least one of the months AND these values are equal).

- User u01 is SELECTED because has the bill rent with the same value on months 201401 and 201402.
- User u02 is NOT selected because has the bill rent with different values on months 201401 and 201402.
- User u03 is NOT selected because has the bill energy with different values on months 201401 and 201402.
- User u04 is SELECTED because has the bill energy with the same value on months 201401 and 201402.
- User u05 is NOT selected because has the bill energy with different values on months 201401 and 201402.
- User u06 is NOT selected because has both  bills (energy and rent) with the value 0 on months 201401 and 201402.

I hope someone can help me.
Ps.: it is a MS SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, but i´m quite new to sql and i´m not getting there (this is only part of the querie, i´m also using CASE to have a result with only one row for each user, with columns like rent_201401, rent_201402, energy_201401, energy_201402 (each one bringing the correspondent "value")... do you have any ideas of code that can sort this out ?

Comment: Showing something that don't work is better than showing nothig at all, yes I have some ideas, but they use the `OVER` clause, the SQLServer you are using is 2005 or better?

Comment: it is: "Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2066"

Comment: My answer should be compatible with that, have you tried it?

Comment: yes, Thankyou !  It worked as a subquery (to filter users) from my original select. I created a version, closer to my reality here [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d75ff/1) ... I will add new data/columns to make it even closer, as on my original database the subquery is not eliminating all the users that don´t follow the criteria ... must be something else i left behind and have to find out what it is =)

Answer (score 0):

Some statistical function will help with this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID
FROM   Utilities
GROUP BY userID, bill
HAVING  AVG(value) > 0
   AND  STDEV(value) = 0
ORDER BY userID
```

`AVG` is the average, the condition is that the average of the value for a bill type is more then 0.
`STDEV` is the standard deviation, long story short, the standard deviation is 0 only when every value in the group is the same.

The compount condition is get me the distinct userID that pays always the same bill.

`STDEV` can be used for any number of rows in the same group (the query will work fine with more then two months of data)

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d77dc/1)